# show file extension on status line in vim

Tags: c++, vim

so this should be simple for a vim guru but basically I have my status line as follows below. It looks great but you will see the file type is [cpp] for .hpp files ideally I want to put just the file extension in the status line like [hpp] so that instead of     /path/file.hpp **[cpp]**  I want it to be /path/file.hpp **[hpp]** so that the below should be replaced with something like

> ```
> set statusline+=\[<file_extension>\]
> ```
>
> instead of `set statusline+=%y`

```
" Status Line {                                                                       
set laststatus=2                             " always show statusbar                  
set statusline=                                                                       
set statusline+=%-10.3n\                     " buffer number                          
set statusline+=%F\                          " filename                               
set statusline+=%h%m%r%w                     " status flags                           
set statusline+=%y                           " file type                              
set statusline+=%=                           " right align remainder                  
set statusline+=0x%-8B                       " character value                        
set statusline+=%-14(%l,%c%V%)               " line, character                        
set statusline+=%<%P                         " file position
```

Comment: You already have that information in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `expand()` function to accomplish this.

```
set statusline+=[%{expand('%:e')}]
```

`%` represents the current file and `:e` means to get the extension.

In my opinion knowing FileType of a current buffer can be quite useful.

For more help see:

```
:h 'statusline'
:h expand(
:h 'filetype'
:h filetype
```

Comment: Thanks yeah I agree filetype is useful I kept that also in the status line but usually I am looking for the header vs source and it's easy to just see it right in the status line

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but still if somebuddy is looking for a better way, just use

```
set statusline+=%{expand(&filetype)}
```

This approach is also buffer agnostic, which means if you have different filetypes opened in splits, the statusline would show different types.

Instead, if you go for this

```
set statusline+=&filetype
```

Filetype for statuslines for entire window would show the filetype of active buffer